# Does ServletContext realpath will work in WAR file

Tags: java, servlets, war

I am storing some formatted excels in the location `ReportGeneratorJSF/WebContent/WEB-INF/FormattedExcel/*.xls`. and to read them i have used `getRealPath("/WEB-INF/FormattedExcel/")` of ServletContext. But its reading from location

```
'C:\Users\kgcn984\heliosworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ReportGeneratorJSF\WEB-INF\FormattedExcel\...'
```

Although the path should have been `ReportGeneratorJSF/WebContent/WEB-INF/FormattedExcel/*.xls`, but its working fine.

My question is when i create a war file and put in webapps of tomcat, will it work successfully, Sorry i cant try it out this, as i dont have system rights to place any war in webapps of tomcat.

please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work correctly if and only if Tomcat has expanded the WAR.

To use the file in all situations, you should use `getResourceAsStream`.

If you need to list all the Excel documents, you can use `getResourcePaths`

Comment: expanded the WAR: does it means it should be a directory based instead of single war file??

I tried the getResourceAsStream but it was returning ByteArrayInputStream, in my code its present as
....
new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(formatFile));
...

Passing the ByteArray.... was not giving compile error but the required formatting cellstyle was not getting applied to the generated excels.

Comment: I'm not sure why `HSSFWorkbook` would have a problem with the `ByteArrayInputStream` but that's a different question. Servlet containers are allowed to run Web Apps from within a WAR or by expanding the WAR - it's up to the container and/or the server administrator to set up which method is used.